# Llamada AJAX a una pagina en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un problema al llamar a una pagina php psandole paramteros por post desde una aplicacon mobile mediante ajax.

en la URL http://mistio.falso.bogus/colectar.php?usuario=admin&pass=admin&pagina=paginap&tiempo=tiempo&fecha=fecha

recibo datos que guardo en una base de datos

El codigo de la pagina es

```
<?php

require_once ("bd/conexion.php");

$nombre = $_POST["usuario"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$nombre = stripslashes($nombre);
$pass = stripslashes($pass);


$pagina = $_POST["pagina"];
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$tiempo = $_POST["tiempo"];

$conexion = new Conexion();

$datos = new Datos();

if ($datos->login($nombre, $pass)) {
    try {
        $datos->insertar_registro($fecha, $pagina, $tiempo);
        echo 'no dio error';
        return TRUE;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
         echo 'dio error';
        return FALSE;
    }

} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Si llamo a la URL con paràmetros desde el navegador puedo ver que se guarda el registro correcto en la base de datos

AHora, no me esta funcionando esta funcion en la aplicaicon mobile

```html
function envioDeDatos(id,pagina,tiempo){
    fechaAux = new Date();
    fecha = fechaAux.getFullYear()+ "-"+ fechaAux.getMonth()+1+"-"+fechaAux.getDate();
    console.log(id,pagina,tiempo);
  
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://misitio.falso.com.com/colectar.php?usuario=admin&pass=pass&pagina="+pagina+"&tiempo="+tiempo+"&fecha="+fecha,
        
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {},
        async: true,
        success: function(){
           db.transaction(function(tx){
               tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM TiempoUso WHERE id="+id);
           },erroresBd);
        },
        error: function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
}
```

Le he dado miles de vueltas al asunto, he probado cambiar todo ppor GET en lugar de post, poner HTML en lugar de json y nada parece funcionar.

Lo unico que quiero hacer con la funcion es armar esa url compuesta y consumirla para poder registrar esos datos

Tengo habilitado el CROSS en el apache

Les agradezco desde ya cualquier ayuda o sugerencia que me puedan dar

Edit: agrego el codigo de la prueba que hice pasandole parametros por data

```
function envioDeDatos(id,pagina,tiempo){
    fechaAux = new Date();
    fecha = fechaAux.getFullYear()+ "-"+ fechaAux.getMonth()+1+"-"+fechaAux.getDate();
    console.log(id,pagina,tiempo);
    usuario = "admin";

    $.ajax({

        url: "http://colector.montevideo-gh.com/colectar.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {usuario: usuario, password: "pass", fecha:fecha, pagina:pagina, tiempo:tiempo},
        async: true,
        success: function(){
           db.transaction(function(tx){
               tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM TiempoUso WHERE id="+id);
           },erroresBd);
        },
        error: function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
}
```

Agrego mas informacion, los cabezales mi php son

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

El error en la consola del servidor es

```
[26-Jan-2019 17:11:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: tiempo in /home/j4v2rcu0st6e/misitio.falso.bogus/colectar.php on line 34
```

y tengo una linea asi por cada variable que deberia pasarme el ajax lo que creo significa que no fueron

Comment: Hola, una pregunta, ¿Porqué quieres pasar la url compuesta? Eso no lo entiendo. ¿No deberías pasar los datos en el campo `data`?

Comment: HIce la prueba y tampoco me anda, por eso intento pasar la URL completa por que me parecio mas facil

Comment: ¿Puedes postear el código de la prueba que hiciste?

Comment: Acabo de editar para poner el codigo que probe

Comment: ¿Puedes probar usando `type="POST"` y `contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`?

Comment: Hice la prueba que me recomiendas tanto con la url compuesta como con los datos por data y en ninguno de los dos casos me funciona y ni siquiera veo un error en el log

Comment: Cuando metes los parámetros en la URL no es POST, es GET.

Comment: probe ambas cosas, ninguna me funciona